# Is there a way to join tables in MS Access to get this output?

Tags: ms-access

Say we have 2 tables:

Table A:

```
EmployeeName
Carter
Rick
Larry
```

Table B:

```
Case
Case1
Case2
Case3
Case4
Case5
Case6
Case7
Case8
```

Now I'd like an output like this:

```
EmployeeName    Case
Carter  Case1
Rick    Case2
Larry   Case3
Carter  Case4
Rick    Case5
Larry   Case6
Carter  Case7
Rick    Case8
```

Can this be done in MS Access using SQL queries?

Comment: No, it can not.

Comment: @KenWhite: A couple of subqueries will help you along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can.

First, create two queries to add *sequential numbers* to the records:

```sql
SELECT 
    Employee.EmployeeName, 
    (Select Count(*) 
    From Employee As T 
    Where T.EmployeeName < Employee.EmployeeName) AS Id
FROM 
    Employee;


SELECT 
    Case.Case, 
    (Select Count(*) 
    From Case As T 
    Where T.Case < Case.Case) AS Id
FROM 
    Case;
```

Save these as *qEmployee* and *qCase*.

Then create the final query:

```sql
SELECT 
    qEmployee.EmployeeName, 
    qCase.Case
FROM 
    qCase, 
    qEmployee
WHERE 
    ([qCase]![Id] Mod (Select Count(*) From Employee)) = [qEmployee]![Id];
```

Output:

[image]

If you don't want employee names to be sorted, another field to sort on must be present.

Comment: Hi Gustav, how do you translate the first 2 sequential queries to LEFT/INNER Join instead of using a sub query?

Comment: You can't. The "join" is made by the Where clause. But you could include them as subqueries in place of qCase and qEmployee respectively - it just makes the final query difficult to read.